# GSON Deserialize String[] to String inside one type

Tags: java, json, gson

This may seem an odd requirement but I want to deserialize a `JSONStringArray` to a `String`, (not a `String[]`).

Example of my object

```
class Retailer {
  String name;
  String images;
}
```

Incoming JSON:

```
{
  "name":"Mr Retailer",
  "images":[
    "http://server.com/image1",
    "http://server.com/image2"
  ]
}
```

So the parsed object would contain the deserilized values like so:

```
name = "Mr Retailer"
images = "http://server.com/image1 http://server.com/image2"
```

The delimiter is not important I will pick one that does not exist in my URLs, e.g. pipe white space etc..

I'm assuming I need to write a `TypeAdapter` for `String[]` to iterate through the JSONArray and concat the elements in the array into a String?

I also only want to do this for that specific class, as other classes have `String[]` but I want to leave them alone.

Comment: How would that string look in this example?

Comment: @Nanne added end result example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Nanne suggested link I created the following custom deserializer.

```
public class RetailerDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Retailer> {

    @Override
    public Retailer deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject retailerObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        final String name = retailerObject.get("name").getAsString();
        JsonArray innerImagesArray = retailerObject.get("innerImages").getAsJsonArray();
        String innerImages = null;
        if (innerImagesArray != null) {
            final String[] innerImagesArr = new String[innerImagesArray.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < innerImagesArray.size(); i++) {
                innerImagesArr[i] = innerImagesArray.get(i).getAsString();
            }
            innerImages = TextUtils.join(" ", innerImagesArr);
        }
        return new Retailer(name, innerImages);
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are better my 'dynamic' suggestions. Any improvements on this I will be willing to accept as answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to deserialize using the normal function(s), leaving you with

```
class Retailer {
  String name;
  String[] images;
}
```

and then either define a class that generates your desired class from that, or define a function `String getImage()` that returns the string from that array?

Comment: I agree with you, but for a couple of reasons that not possible in this case.

Comment: Well, then you need to register a TypeAdapter indeed, but I would just do it for that `images` 'object'. See for instance this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014674/gson-custom-deseralizer-for-one-variable-in-an-object