# use JsonDeserializer on GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a model that work with multiple JSON responses. However this a response :

```
items: [
{
kind: "youtube#playlistItem",
etag: ""fpJ9onbY0Rl_LqYLG6rOCJ9h9N8/jqbcTLu8tYm8b1FXGO14gNZrFG4"",
id: "PLUQ7I1jJqKB4lJarGcpWsP62l7iC06IkE2LDE0BxLe18",
```

That conflict with this one (notice the same `id` field with different type. The above `id` is `String`, the other is a `Class`) :

```
items: [
{
kind: "youtube#searchResult",
etag: ""fpJ9onbY0Rl_LqYLG6rOCJ9h9N8/hDIU49vmD5aPhKUN5Yz9gtljG9A"",
id: {
kind: "youtube#playlist",
playlistId: "PLh6xqIvLQJSf3ynKVEc1axUb1dQwvGWfO"
},
```

I want to read the `id` field using a single model class.

This is my model `Response` class :

```
public class Response {
    private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

And this is my model `Item` class :

```
public class Item {
    private Id id;

//nested class inside Item
public class Id
{
    private String id;
    private String kind;
    private String playlistId;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public String getPlaylistId() {
        return playlistId;
    }

    public void setPlaylistId(String playlistId) {
        this.playlistId = playlistId;
    }
}
```

Notice that the `Id` class is inside `Item` class.

This is how i use `registerTypeAdapter` :

```
 GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Response.class,
                    new JsonDeserializer<Item.Id>() {
                        @Override
                        public Item.Id deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
                            Item.Id result = new Item().new Id();

                            if(jsonElement.isJsonPrimitive() == false)
                            {
                                result.setKind(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("kind").getAsString());
                                result.setPlaylistId(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("playlistId").getAsString());
                                //return new Item.Id(jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("kind").getAsString(), jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("playlistId").getAsString());
                                return result;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                result.setId(jsonElement.getAsString());
                                //return new Item.Id(jsonElement.getAsString());
                                return result;
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

            Response result = Response.success(
                    gson.fromJson(json, gsonClass),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
```

However the above code throws `java.lang.NullPointerException` in this line :

```
if(jsonElement.isJsonPrimitive() == false)
```

What should i do?
Is this the correct way to use `registerTypeAdapter`?

Thanks for your time

Comment: What is the value of the json you're passing in? And how is Response.class defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem seems to be that you're registering a type adapter for `Response` class but you're giving a `JsonDeserializer` that handles `Item.Id` classes. Either you deserialize a full `Response` or limit yourself to `Item` or even `Item.Id`.

Another problem with deserializing `Item.Id` (as written in your question) directly is that it's a **non**-*static* inner class, which requires an instance of the parent class to be instantiated (as you do with the `new Item().new Id()`). I think that you would have to deserialize the whole `Item` manually if you want to keep it as such, frankly I don't see any reason not to make `Item.Id` static as it would simplify the problem.

Here's my solution with the static version of `Item.Id`

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Item.Id.class, new JsonDeserializer<Item.Id>() {
    @Override
    public Item.Id deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Item.Id id = new Item.Id();
        if (!json.isJsonPrimitive()) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
            id.setKind(jsonObject.get("kind").getAsString());
            id.setPlaylistId(jsonObject.get("playlistId").getAsString());
        } else {
            id.setId(json.getAsString());
        }
        return id;
    }
});
```

And some test snippets that seemed to work for me:

```
Gson gson = builder.create();
Response response = gson.fromJson("{\n" +
        "    \"items\": [\n" +
        "        {\n" +
        "            \"kind\": \"youtube#playlistItem\",\n" +
        "            \"etag\": \"fpJ9onbY0Rl_LqYLG6rOCJ9h9N8/jqbcTLu8tYm8b1FXGO14gNZrFG4\",\n" +
        "            \"id\": \"PLUQ7I1jJqKB4lJarGcpWsP62l7iC06IkE2LDE0BxLe18\"\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "    ]\n" +
        "}", Response.class);

Response response2 = gson.fromJson("{\n" +
        "    \"items\": [\n" +
        "        {\n" +
        "            \"kind\": \"youtube#searchResult\",\n" +
        "            \"etag\": \"fpJ9onbY0Rl_LqYLG6rOCJ9h9N8/hDIU49vmD5aPhKUN5Yz9gtljG9A\",\n" +
        "            \"id\": {\n" +
        "                \"kind\": \"youtube#playlist\",\n" +
        "                \"playlistId\": \"PLh6xqIvLQJSf3ynKVEc1axUb1dQwvGWfO\"\n" +
        "            }\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "    ]\n" +
        "}", Response.class);
```

If you want to keep `Item.Id` non-static, I think you need to write a deserializer for `Item` instead. Also keep in mind that json elements can be absent but the parser should still be able to handle it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort to write this answer. Its too bad i can only upvote once. Hope someone else will upvote this great answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: If i may add a question, why do i need to deserialize the whole `Item` if i dont make the inner `Id` class static?

Comment: @BlazeTama I'm not 100% sure on that, actually, but instances of non-static inner classes have a reference to their parent, so I would imagine that you'd need that reference in order to create an instance of it... I'm not sure if there's some magic underneath in java that changes that reference to another parent class instance when you assign it to another instance of the parent (I think not). If it works like I think it does, you'd end up with Id that refers internally to some other Item instance.

Answer (score 1):

I had just the same problem long time ago, but i was working then with Json.Net, However json concept is (almost) the same so I hope I will succeed help.
I guess it might not work, but why try to not register with the Item class? I mean there is no 'Item.Id' in so it's obious get a null.  BUT this: `gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Item.class,` likely to fail, becaus you dont parse the Item class explicitly (However it might work, I just never tried it in Gson. But in Json.Net similar way would work proper.)
So, how could you fix that? I'm too lazy to write an paraser but you could look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014674/gson-custom-deseralizer-for-one-variable-in-an-object) and read  the surt summary summary from [here](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/) (Search for `Using the registerTypeAdapter()`.
I hope I helped.