# how to use Gson to map a JSON to a class with different structure

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following class

```
class MyList{
 List<String> names ;
}
```

and a Json structure

```
{
 "names" :[
     {"name":"John"},
     {"name":"David"}
  ]
}
```

As you can see the `JSON` structure isn't exactly mapping the `class` structure.

Is there **an easy way** to map the json to the desired class?

So per say the following:

```
    Namese names = new Gson().fromJson(json, Names.class);
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(names);
```

will printout :

```
["John","David"]
```

If there isn't a way using `Gson`, is there any other library that let's me do it **easily**?

**NOTE**

by using word **easy** I mean without manually looping through our json structure and create the class.

Comment: What do you need? Parsing the JSON to Java objects or serialiazing Java objects to JSON...or both?

Comment: @C.Champagne I'm looking for an easy way to convert a json to Java that their structure aren't exactly the same

Comment: No, there is no easy/one-line-of-code way. You need to modify the model or create custom adapter for names property

Comment: As Vlodomyr pointed, I don't think there is an *easy* way, as you meant at least. Can't you adapt your JSON or your class to make them match? (I suppose you would have done it if you could but...who knows?)

Comment: Either you follow the conventions or you go low level. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014674/gson-custom-deseralizer-for-one-variable-in-an-object

Comment: @C.Champagne I've been just trying to be lazy and make use of our current legacy data source. seems there is no way around it